# typecasting a pointer to an int crashes

Tags: c++

I used to think both the cout statements point to the same value even though one prints in hex and other in integer format.
But today i ran the same on g++ to find the second statement crashes.

```
int i1=12;
int *p1=&i1;

cout<<*(*((int***)&p1)); cout<<"\n\n           "; //is same
cout<<*(int*)*(int*)&p1; cout<<"\n           "; //is same
```

Why would it crash when effectively the second statement is same as printing value of `i1`.

Comment: Can you provide more information? Is it a compiler error? What is the error message?

Comment: Its a core dump(segmentation fault). Compiles fine.

Comment: Are you by any chance compiling on a 64 bit system?

Comment: Why would you even attempt this monstrosity? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: We need more asterisks

Comment: @GillBates `******************************************************` :-)

Comment: Guys chill! I just asked a question i didnt asked for a kidney for you to behave this ...lol. @user1937198 : yes its 64 bit machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is simply wrong and a normal compiler warns you:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:10:32: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
     std::cout<< *(int*)*(int*)&p1 <<std::endl;
```

And there is no need for a c-style cast and definitely no need for the wrong cast :-)
                                   ^

The correct code is:

```
 std::cout<< *(int*)*(int**)&p1 <<std::endl;
```

because the address of a pointer to int is an `int**`

Some more explanation as requested :-)

What each step of the evaluation does:

> `p1` is a int* and points to your i1
>
> `&p1` is a int** because it is a pointer to pointer to int.
>
> `*(&p1)` dereferences the pointer so it becomes a pointer to int ( int*)
>
> `*(*(&p1))`  dereferences the resulting pointer so it becomes an int.

And what you did with your casts:

> `&p1` again is the address of the pointer to pointer (int**)
>
> `(int*)&p1` !Ubs! Now the compiler must treat your pointer to pointer as
>       pointer to int. That is a valid expression but not very useful.
>
> `*(int*)&p1` Now the compiler dereferences the (int*) to an int. This is 
>       still a valid expression but the value stored is not guaranteed the same as before. As explained later, you will loose a part of the value exactly here!
>
> `(int*)*(int*)&p1` Now you tell the compiler it should use your int value
>       as a pointer. Still not crashing but not longer valid. See next step:
>
> `*(int*)*(int*)&p1` Crash! Now you try to dereference the int value.
>       This is working ( but not correct code ) as long the int can store a
>       valid pointer. But on a 64 bit machine a pointer have mostly
>       64 bits ( not a must !) and an int uses
>       32 bits ( typically, also not a must! ). As a result only the half of the
>       pointer is used and points not to a valid address which results in the
>       crash.

Use the following code example to get the different pointer values on a 64bit machine:

```
int i1=12;
int *p1=&i1;

std::cout << (int*)*(int*)&p1 << std::endl;
std::cout << (int*)*(int**)&p1 << std::endl;
```

On my 32bit machine both values are the same. On your machine, if 64bit, you will see different values! And the first value is not longer pointing to a valid address. And also on my 32 bit machine the compiler warns about the wrong usage of the pointer. You should never ignore a compiler warning!

And on my 32 bit machine the code you wrote works also fine but is undefined behavior and also results in a compiler warning.

Hope that helps :-)

Comment: And then the casts are unnecessary. Like much of the rest of the code.

Comment: The complete code is useless :-) But if someone wants understand the basics... why not?

Comment: These _aren't_ "the basics [of C++]". They are the basics of some arbitrary fiction that has no basis in reality. What's the point in that?

Comment: You should not ask me but the OP for the reason of such question... I personally have no need for cast gymnastics at all. And to print a "12" I have no need to do such mysterious things :-)

Comment: You asked me a question; I answered! I have little interest in asking the OP because I have a feeling we would not like the answer.

Comment: @Klaus : thnx first of for supporting my intent of learning rather than being judgemental...Could you please explain why `int**` is correct .By `cout<<*(int*)*(int*)&p1; cout<<"\n ` I just meant address of p1 sholud be treated as a pointer to an int which is dereferenced once which becomes int, which again is treated as pointer to int dereferenced once. If what you said is the reason for crash then `cout<<*(int*)&p1;` shold also crash. Even a simple `int i=9; cout<<*(int*) i` shold crash, but it doesnt.

Comment: @anurag86 Because when it becomes an int, you are telling the compilier it can treat the value as `int`, rather than an `int*`. Doing so is undefined behavior, so the compiler does not have to treat it consistently. On the machine you are compiling on, `int*` and `int**` are probably identical at the machine level, whilst `int` is half the size. And `int i=9; cout<<*(int*) i` should crash as well, but the compilier may have optimized the code to a noop, as it is guaranteed to be undefined behaviour.

Comment: @anurag86: I add some more information. I hope you can get the point.

Comment: this is exactly the kind of reasoning i was looking for...crisp clear...thanks a ton

Answer (score 6):

You can't just pretend pointers and integers are the same thing like this. Your code makes a ton of assumptions about type width and alignment, aliasing things with the wrong type then dereferencing. *All* of it has undefined behaviour. If it "worked" before you were "lucky".

Just throw it away and write something that makes sense per the semantics of the C++ language.

Comment: And i am trying to understand exactly what you said was wrong. Hence this question :) . My intent is not to write a code which does something sensible but to try things right and left to understand what works and what doesnt which imo is the best way to learn(be it music be it any language). You need not explain me in detail instead if you could help me out with the few topics which you think will clarify the doubts that i have in my head then i would be more than happy and thankful to you.

Comment: @anurag86: Just don't do weird things with pointers that don't make sense. Don't pretend that an `int*` is an `int**` or an `int***` or even an `int`. It is not. It is an `int*`. That's all there is to say!